# HTML5 drag&drop - sortable list and Web Storage

Tags: javascript, html

Can I reload current page without losing any drag&drop positions i made with Web Storage ?

This is the link of the example

[Example](http://www.osmg.club/new2/index.html)

How can I get that if change position item 1 with item 6 that these positions remain on same place even if I refresh the page. Because of the information changes in items box page must be refreshed.

Here is code

```
    <!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>HTML5 Sortable jQuery Plugin</title>
    <style>
        header, section {
            display: block;
        }
        body {
            font-family: 'Droid Serif';
        }
        h1, h2 {
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: normal;
        }
        #features {
            margin: auto;
            width: 460px;
            font-size: 0.9em;
        }
        .connected, .sortable, .exclude, .handles {
            margin: auto;
            padding: 0;
            -webkit-touch-callout: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }
        .sortable.grid {
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .connected li, .sortable li, .exclude li, .handles li {
            list-style: none;
            border: 1px solid #CCC;
            background: #F6F6F6;
            font-family: "Tahoma";
            color: #1C94C4;
            margin: 5px;
            padding: 5px;
            height: 22px;
        }
        .handles span {
            cursor: move;
        }
        li.disabled {
            opacity: 0.5;
        }
        .sortable.grid li {
            float: left;
            width: 350px;
            height: 200px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        li.highlight {
            background: #FEE25F;
        }
        #connected {
            width: 440px;
            overflow: hidden;
            margin: auto;
        }
        .connected {
            float: left;
            width: 200px;
        }
        .connected.no2 {
            float: right;
        }
        li.sortable-placeholder {
            border: 1px dashed #CCC;
            background: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <section>
        <h2>Sortable Grid</h2>
        <ul class="sortable grid">
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
            <li>Item 5</li>
            <li>Item 6</li>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
            <li>Item 5</li>
            <li>Item 6</li>
        </ul>
    </section>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.sortable.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('.sortable').sortable();
            $('.handles').sortable({
                handle: 'span'
            });
            $('.connected').sortable({
                connectWith: '.connected'
            });
            $('.exclude').sortable({
                items: ':not(.disabled)'
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and js file

```
    (function($) {
var dragging, placeholders = $();
$.fn.sortable = function(options) {
    var method = String(options);
    options = $.extend({
        connectWith: false
    }, options);
    return this.each(function() {
        if (/^enable|disable|destroy$/.test(method)) {
            var items = $(this).children($(this).data('items')).attr('draggable', method == 'enable');
            if (method == 'destroy') {
                items.add(this).removeData('connectWith items')
                    .off('dragstart.h5s dragend.h5s selectstart.h5s dragover.h5s dragenter.h5s drop.h5s');
            }
            return;
        }
        var isHandle, index, items = $(this).children(options.items);
        var placeholder = $('<' + (/^ul|ol$/i.test(this.tagName) ? 'li' : 'div') + ' class="sortable-placeholder">');
        items.find(options.handle).mousedown(function() {
            isHandle = true;
        }).mouseup(function() {
            isHandle = false;
        });
        $(this).data('items', options.items)
        placeholders = placeholders.add(placeholder);
        if (options.connectWith) {
            $(options.connectWith).add(this).data('connectWith', options.connectWith);
        }
        items.attr('draggable', 'true').on('dragstart.h5s', function(e) {
            if (options.handle && !isHandle) {
                return false;
            }
            isHandle = false;
            var dt = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
            dt.effectAllowed = 'move';
            dt.setData('Text', 'dummy');
            index = (dragging = $(this)).addClass('sortable-dragging').index();
        }).on('dragend.h5s', function() {
            dragging.removeClass('sortable-dragging').show();
            placeholders.detach();
            if (index != dragging.index()) {
                items.parent().trigger('sortupdate', {item: dragging});
            }
            dragging = null;
        }).not('a[href], img').on('selectstart.h5s', function() {
            this.dragDrop && this.dragDrop();
            return false;
        }).end().add([this, placeholder]).on('dragover.h5s dragenter.h5s drop.h5s', function(e) {
            if (!items.is(dragging) && options.connectWith !== $(dragging).parent().data('connectWith')) {
                return true;
            }
            if (e.type == 'drop') {
                e.stopPropagation();
                placeholders.filter(':visible').after(dragging);
                return false;
            }
            e.preventDefault();
            e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
            if (items.is(this)) {
                if (options.forcePlaceholderSize) {
                    placeholder.height(dragging.outerHeight());
                }
                dragging.hide();
                $(this)[placeholder.index() < $(this).index() ? 'after' : 'before'](placeholder);
                placeholders.not(placeholder).detach();
            } else if (!placeholders.is(this) && !$(this).children(options.items).length) {
                placeholders.detach();
                $(this).append(placeholder);
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: "Because of the information changes in items box page must be refreshed" Are you sure about that? What about AJAX?

Comment: AJAX is ok but it's hard for me

Comment: While this code  provides nice solution for sorting via drag&drop, it completely lacks the ability to 1) save any new ordering 2) load the tiles initially in any different order than sequentially (because it's hardcoded in the markup). So these are the two main problems you should address. Once you are able to "remember" a new order, e.g. in a cookie or localStorage, you can take 2 approaches to solve the second problem: either send the saved order with the request and have the markup be ordered by the server or load in initial order and rearrange after page load using JS.